# What is the fastest way to auto open hash tab on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I want to open hash #home automatically on page load. I tried

```
<body onload=window.location='#home'>
```

JS way:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function load()
    {
    window.location.href = "#home";

    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="load()">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And html redirect

```
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=#home" />
```

All ways are too slow (about 2-3 sec. to redirect after page load). Is there any better (faster) way to automatically open #home on page load?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
<body onload="window.location.hash='home'">
```

I think this is the fastest way.

Comment: I have tried this, but probably it is faster way. About 1.5 - 2 seconds. But it is the same as <body onload=window.location='#home'>

Comment: but there is problem, when i refresh page it jump to homepage

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to the specified tag, set the id of any div or control with "home".

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{
window.location.href = "#home";

}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<div id="home">Some content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried this way, but proslem is thah when i refresh page it jumo to homepage

Answer (score 0):

I found best solution. There is no load time. It check hash and if there is no hash (first page load) open hash tab #home. Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
var x = location.hash.replace("#","");
if (x==="")
  {
window.location.href = "#home";

  }
  });
      </script>
```

Really i tried many ways but this is the best and fastest.